# NavigationView and ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, android-design-library

With the new `NavigationView` is it still recommended to use `ActionBarDrawerToggle` or is this not "Material Design"?  For instance previously we were supposed to hide action bar items when the drawer was opened but now the guidelines say that they should stay.

Answer (score 17):

> With the new `NavigationView` is it still recommended to use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`

No, it's not required.

If you look at the "official" [demo code](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) for the new Design Library, `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is no longer used, since the new `NavigationView` and `AppCompatActivity` don't really need it.

With the new v22 support library, you can strip out all of your `ActionBarDrawerToggle` code and just use the following to handle the interaction between `NavigationDrawer` and the `ActionBar`/`ToolBar` hamburger icon:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        ....
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

You will need to provide your own "hamburger" drawable (`R.drawable.ic_menu` in my example). Besides that, the above code is all that's needed to handle opening of the drawer. The `android.R.id.home` case in `onOptionsItemSelected()` represents your hamburger drawer button. It points to a built-in resource id (**not** something you add to you menu xml), and it's handled automatically.

Besides that, you have to implement closing of the drawer by simply adding `closeDrawers()` to your click listener, like this:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            // Handle menu item clicks here.
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

`closeDrawers()` is a method of DrawerLayout, and takes care of everything. That's it. That's all the code you really need to properly handle navigation drawers now. No more messy code for flipping hamburgers and such!

Of course, if you really want to, you can still use `NavigationView` with `ActionBarDrawerToggle` the old way. But you certainly don't have to.

**If you want drawer callbacks**

Even though `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is not required to open/close the drawer, it may still be useful for handling additional callbacks (especially if you're using ActionBar already). Otherwise, you can implement your own by using `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener` or by using `DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener()`, to handle other open/close related events.

Comment: What if I'm using a NavigationDrawer in an app without the need of the NavigationHeader? Then I would let the drawer open beneath the Toolbar. Should I use ActionBarDrawerToggle to open and close the drawer?

Comment: If drawing NavigationDrawer underneath your Toolbar, that sounds like a good reason to still use ActionBarDrawerToggle. I hadn't thought of that use case, but it looks like someone else has (see the answer from @androidpotato7).

Comment: Thank you very much.  The official document (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) misled me and wasted me a few hours. Now, the code is much simpler and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> With the new `NavigationView` is it still recommended to use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`

Yes. The two tackle two completely different aspects of the navigation drawer.

In total, there are generally three components to a navigation drawer:

- A `DrawerLayout`
- Your navigation drawer content
- A method of showing and hiding the drawer

The `DrawerLayout` is the layout that holds the navigation drawer content and your app's content. It is what allows you to pull the drawer in from the side and display the drawer over your app's content (the first child of the `DrawerLayout`).

Your navigation drawer content (the second child of your `DrawerLayout`) is typically a list of items that the user can click on. Previously, most implementations that I have seen used a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView` and maybe a header of some sort. `NavigationView` is a replacement for this, and is used to provide Material-compliant drawer contents.

`ActionBarDrawerToggle` is used to provide the hamburger icon in your app bar. It is what allows your users to tap on the icon to open or close your drawer.

Comment: the ActionBarDrawerToggle exists only to serve as a listener for open and closing of the drawer. It also allows for the animation between hamburger and arrow to exist. It is not necessary in the Navigation View for opening or closing.

Answer (score 0):

Completing the other answers, the Navigation View should be fit into the whole screen in terms of height so it will hide the hamburger icon when opened. Because of this, having the animation from burger to arrow or even just showing the arrow is not necessary.

But when clicking on the current screen it goes to another fragment, imagine a gallery of photos and clicking on a photo will show it bigger, there should be an animation from burger to arrow and the arrow should stay and when pressed there should be a reverse animation to the burger so the navigation view can be opened again.

You can achieve this with ActionBarDrawerToggle still, even with navigation view because it uses the same DrawerLayout as before. So it still has uses, but of course not necessary.