# Navigation Drawer is opened on activity start

Tags: android

My navigation drawer is opening on app start and I can't find a way to make it go in, not even with back button pressed, how do I make it not open on activity start, plus hide it on a swipe gesture?

This is the code I have on the activity the nav drawer is being displayed.

```
public class BottomActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton Rd1, Rd2, Rd3, Rd4;
DrawerLayout drawer;
ImageView ProfilePic;

@SuppressLint({"RtlHardcoded", "ClickableViewAccessibility"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_bottom );

    Objects.requireNonNull( getSupportActionBar() ).setDisplayOptions( ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM );
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView( R.layout.abs_layout_home );


    radioGroup = findViewById( R.id.radioGroup );
    Rd1 = findViewById( R.id.radioButton );
    Rd2 = findViewById( R.id.radioButton2 );
    Rd3 = findViewById( R.id.radioButton3 );
    Rd4 = findViewById( R.id.radioButton4 );
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (Rd1.isChecked()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), BottomActivity.class );
                startActivity( intent );
            }
            if (Rd2.isChecked()) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), DashBoard.class );
                startActivity( intent1 );
            }
            if (Rd3.isChecked()) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class );
                startActivity( intent2 );
            } else {
                if (Rd4.isChecked()) {
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), Messages.class );
                    startActivity( intent3 );
                }
            }
        }
    } );

       Toolbar Toolbar = findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
    DrawerLayout Drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, Drawer, Toolbar, "Drawer is opened", "Drawer is closed");
    Drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

}



}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen( GravityCompat.START )) {
        drawer.closeDrawer( GravityCompat.START );
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        startActivity( new Intent( BottomActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class ) );
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
        startActivity( new Intent( BottomActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class ) );

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    }

    return true;
}

public void onClickButtonListener() {

    ProfilePic = findViewById( R.id.ProfilePicture );

    ProfilePic.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( BottomActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class );
            startActivity( intent );
        }
    } );


}
}
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav_drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It is expected to open on swipe left gesture and not start on activity start, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `DrawerLayout` won't open its drawer on its own. Are you sure you don't have a call to `openDrawer()` somewhere? Also, from your description of the back press, it sounds like you might have another `NavigationView` somewhere in the `app_bar_nav_drawer` layout, or in another layout `<include>`d therein. The layout you've shown is correct, so it shouldn't be that one. What happens if you swipe from the edge? Does another drawer open over the one that's already there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a [ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle) on your Activity's `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawer, mToolbar, "Drawer is opened", "Drawer is closed");
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    ...
}
```

That will do the trick and handle the show/hide actions for you. You could still accomplish that without the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, but I think it is not worth the effort (Check [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580478/navigationview-and-actionbardrawertoggle) for more information about this)

Comment: I added those lines of code to my onCreate() code block, but I get the "(this, Drawer, Toolbar, "Drawer is opened", "Drawer is closed") "underlined in red.

Comment: @TomasMota Well I didn't clarify because I thought it was implicit in there ...  `mDrawer` is a variable holding a reference to your `DrawerLayout` and `mToolbar` a variable pointing to your Toolbar. So you have to create those two variables and a get a reference using `findViewById` (or a library such as ButterKnife).

Comment: Here it says that the "ActionBarDrawerToggle" cannot be applied to "toolbar" and both of the Strings.

Comment: @TomasMota you will have to update your question with the full code of what are trying, it will be impossible for me to help otherwise

Comment: Okay man, there you go, my full class code, so I am trying to prevent my navigation drawer to open on the activity start, which I don't know what line of code is making it open. I would also like to add some code block to make it open/close on a left swipe gesture.

Comment: @TomasMota Your drawer is being opened at the beginning because of this line `drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);` , remove it and it shouldn't open on start. Then, you are missing the `toolbar` in the constructor of `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, so it should look like this `toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_open);`. If it doesn't work, check the version of the import packages. Once you can configure the ActionBarDrawerToggle properly, your drawer will open/close on swipe gesture

Comment: I have deleted that line of code drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);  but it still opens on activity start.

Comment: @TomasMota weird... try removing the method `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` , it is not necessary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192964/discussion-between-tomas-mota-and-dglozano).

Comment: Already did that, I also updated my code here, give it a look, I have no idea on why it is not working, I have also declared the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

please add this attribute :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 ....
 android:gravity="right"
 ....>
```

Comment: First of all, Thank you for you answer, it didn’t work, my navigation drawer still pops up in the start of my activity.

Comment: Also, I can't even add "android:gravity="right" to that widget.

Comment: Why you can't? Im using it in my drawer attribute

Comment: I was hoping you could tell me that man, it just doesn't appear as available, the only available line of code I can use is "android:layout_gravitiy="right".

Comment: Believe me im using it , and it's weird in your case but anyway i just wanted to help !

Comment: Haha I know man, thank you for you help, I deeply appreciate it.